# How to return rows in LINQ and MVC ,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have model with LINQ that will return Rows. here my code in model class on this query i want to return the result in View. how can i do that?

```
    public void retNumRecord(string email, string fname, 
                             string lname, string zip, string pref, 
                             string address, string tel)
    {
        int _pref = Convert.ToInt32(pref); 

        var x = (from p in db.eduardo_member_t
                 where (p.email != null && p.email.Contains(email))
                    || (p.fname != null && p.fname.Contains(fname))
                    || (p.lname != null && p.lname.Contains(lname))
                    || (p.zip != null && p.zip.Contains(zip))
                    || (p.pref != null && p.pref == _pref)
                    || (p.address != null && p.address.Contains(address))
                    || (p.tel != null && p.tel.Contains(tel))
                 select p); 

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: is void but you are returning x. (?)

Comment: sorry for the confusion .. my program have a search form and by that query i want to return the result in View. how can i do that. im confuse doint this in MVC 3?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that as a model in your view and the call

```
return View( retNumRecord(...) );
```

in your action

Comment: You should read some tutorials about mvc3, it's the fist thing they told. you need to put whatever type that query return as the view mdoel (http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/13/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-strongly-typed-views-in-razor.aspx) and then pass the query result as a parameter of the View method in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

A void will not return anything. You need an `ActionResult`.

```
public ActionResult retNumRecord(....
{
   .....

   return View(x);
}
```

This assumes you have a view called 'retNumRecord', if not then:

```
return View("yourviewname", x);
```

Or, if this is an ajax call:

```
return Json(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call the method in your controller and then return View(retNumRecord(..));

Right click on your controller name and then create a view. Once you are in the view, You can make a for loop to print out each row.

Follow the [music store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) as it can get you up to speed with MVC3